# How to concat two string values in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity

Concat two or more string values-

```
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract StringConcatation{
    function AppendString(string memory a, string memory b) public pure returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(a,"-",b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:** As mentioned in another answer by @MAMY Sébastien, since Solidity 0.8.12 you can finally use `string.concat()` for this:

```
string.concat(a, "-", b);
```

---

Old answer:

This is the canonical way to do it currently:

```
string(bytes.concat(bytes(a), "-", bytes(b)));
```

Your example still works and is fine though. `bytes.concat()` was added because `abi.encodePacked()` might be deprecated in favor of having more specific functions at some point in the future. Concatenating `bytes` arrays before hashing seems to be its main use case for now.

The conversions make the use of `bytes.concat()` for `string` a bit verbose, which is why [`string.concat()` is going to be introduced in future versions](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/12087).

Answer (score 4):

From Solidity 0.8.12, you can use `string.concat()` to concatenate strings. Your code will look like:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.12;

contract StringConcatation {
    function AppendString(string memory a, string memory b) public pure returns (string memory) {
        return string.concat(a,"-",b);
    }
}
```

source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=concat#the-functions-bytes-concat-and-string-concat